# Creating a custom date in smarty, using the year from a variable and the month and day of my choosing?

Tags: smarty

I'm brand new to this, so go easy on me. I'm trying to pull just the date from the trip start date, use it in a custom date, so that each year, the date I am using in my IF statements doesn't have to be updated.

```
{$trip->start|date_format:'%Y'}
```

Will give me the year the trip is taking place. I only want certain information to be included in an email if it is being sent before April 15th of that same year.

```
{if $smarty.now <= strtotime(INSERT DATE HERE 0415)}
```

This is where I need help. How do I get it to pull the year from the trip, then use it to create April 15th of that year, then convert it using strtotime, so I can use it to limit what is sent?

I have tried this:

```
{assign var="tripyear" value="$trip->start|date_format:'%Y'"}
{if strtotime($trip->start) >= strtotime("$tripyear"0415)}
{if $smarty.now <= strtotime("$tripyear"0415)}
```

But I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code below assigns the year of the trip to 'tripyear'. It's like you said, but some brackets were missing:

```html
{assign var="tripyear" value="{$trip->start|date_format:'%Y'}"}
```

If you type this, you will display today's date:

```html
{$smarty.now|date_format}
```

If you type this, it will display the date of April 15 in the year of `$tripyear`:

```html
{strtotime("{$tripyear}-04-15")|date_format}
```

By typing the code below, you will only display the text "hello" if today (`$smarty.now`) is earlier or on the same date as April 15 in the year of `$tripyear`.

```html
{if $smarty.now <= strtotime("{$tripyear}-04-15")}
    hello
{/if}
```